# Why does my Recursion using Pointer in C crash?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, crash

I'm currently studying Computer Science and we started working with Pointers. I had the feeling that I started to understand pointers but I ran into a problem and can't figure out what went wrong.

We defined a Tree like this:

```
typedef struct node *tree;
struct node {int key; tree left, right;};
```

Now we should write a function that creates nodes with three parameters, the key of the node, the left node and the right node that should be "below" the node. I did it like this and it seemed to work:

```
tree createNode(int n, tree l, tree r){
    tree node = (tree) malloc(sizeof(tree));
    node->key = n;
    node->left = l;
    node->right = r;
    return node;
}
```

Finally we should write a function that multiplies all leaves of the Tree and i thought the easiest way would be to start at the root and search for the leaves through a recursion and then multiply them. But when i call the function the program seem to crash in the middle of the function. My function looks like this:

```
int leafprod(tree t){
    printf("%d\n", t->key);

    if (t->left == NULL){
        if (t->right == NULL){
            printf("$1\n\n");
            return t->key;
        }
        printf("$2\n\n");
        return leafprod(t->right);
    }
    if (t->right == NULL){
        printf("$3\n\n");
        return leafprod(t->left);
    }
    printf("$4\n\n");
    return leafprod(t->left) * leafprod(t->right);
}
```

and i call the function in the main function like this:

```
int main(){
    tree a = createNode(1, NULL, NULL);
    tree b = createNode(2, NULL, NULL);
    tree c = createNode(3, a, NULL);
    tree d = createNode(4, b, c);

    int n = leafprod(d);

    printf("end: %d", n);

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    free(d);

    return 0;
}
```

I used the print statements to follow the programm and try to locate the error, but in most cases it prints nothing. Then sometimes it prints:

```
4
$4

2
$2
```

And only two times the program went through the whole code. I believe maybe I am using the malloc function wrong but I cannot tell.

Comment: At least this line tree node = (tree) malloc(sizeof(tree)); is incorrect. There must be tree node = (tree) malloc(sizeof( *tree));

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think you need `sizeof(*l)` or `sizeof(*r)` (as `tree` is s type).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This results to the error "type name is not allowed".

Comment: Don't hide pointer types with typedefs as you did here: `typedef struct node* tree;` It only causes confusion, at least in your case here it obviously does.

Comment: As @wohlstad said, you can use `sizeof(*l)` or `sizeof(*r)`, but you could also use `sizeof(*node)` or `sizeof(struct node)`.

Comment: @wohlstad It was a typo.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
tree node = (tree) malloc(sizeof(tree));
```

`tree` is typedef for a pointer to `struct node`.
Therefore `sizeof(tree)` is just the size of the pointer.

You should one of the following instead:

```
tree node = malloc(sizeof(*l));
```

Or:

```
tree node = malloc(sizeof(*r));
```

`*l` and `*r` are of type `struct node` (not a pointer) and this is the element you are trying to create.

Another option as @IanAbbott commented is:

```
tree node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
```

Note that `node` here is the name of the variable, not the type (which in C requires to be prefixes with `struct`, i.e. `struct node`).
The advantage of this approach is that the statement is not dependent on other variables.

**Side notes:**

1. You shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`. See here:[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
2. It's not a good practice to hide pointer types with typedefs. You can consider to avoid it (you can use `typedef struct node Node` if you want to save the need to use the `struct` keyword everywhere).

Comment: Hiding pointer types with typedefs is a terrible thing....

Comment: More canonically, you could use `tree node = malloc(sizeof(*node));` rather than referring to other variables.

Comment: @IanAbbott yeah, i like this one more. Thank you guys i really struggeled with this one :D

Comment: @Jabberwocky added a note about the pointer typedef.

Comment: @IanAbbott initially I thought you were wrong, the name of the struct `node` being identical to the variable confused me. Updated my answer with your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the typedef for hiding pointer types.

With `typedef struct node *tree;` you have no idea what `tree` is in your code hence the confusion.

Typically here `tree node = (tree) malloc(sizeof(tree))` you did it wrong, and the main reason was probably because you didn't know anymore what `tree` actually was.

```
...
struct node 
{
  int key;
  struct node* left;
  struct node *right;
};

struct node* createNode(int n, struct node*l, struct node*r) {

  struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));   // don't use the cast, it's useless
   ...
}


int leafprod(struct node* t) {
...
```